Can't open a project in unity, because it keeps loading infinitely
After installing URP and Shader Graph from unity package, i closed my project, after a while I opened it again and my project stuck in "Compilling Scripts: ScriptCompilation: Running Backend", I've left it loading for more than 4 hours, and it's still stuck in the same place.loading print
I've already tried to reinstall unity hub, and I've looked for several solutions, but none of them really worked, I just wanted to open my project, and not redo it from 0.
I am using Windows.
The editor version is: 2022.3.10f1.

Hello, please give a bit more context. Did you use a different RP before installing URP? Are you sure that dependent files are not opened in another program? Also, have you checked the editor logs for any clues? Regarding Unity Hub, don't bother, your problem is not related to it.

I used to have a similar problem in the past, although im not shure what i did. Try to reinstall the Unity Editor instead of the hub.
Also you should specify the OS, as for me it was on Linux

Quit Unity, delete the Library directory, reopen the project and watch the editor.log file for any errors. You might also consider rebooting after closing Unity just to be sure you are starting from a clean slate. Reinstalling Unity and Unity Hub are just desperation steps. Opening a project doesn't modify either installation and if it was corrupted in some way it's unlikely everything but loading your specific project would work.

Delete the library folder. Try again

No, I didn't use a different RP before the universal.

I reinstalled unity editor and the problem is still persisting.

Have you tried force quitting the program or application?
You could also comment out that line.

I already tried to do that.

Try creating a new project and copy all of the code and assets in apart from the Unity URP and Shader Graph, see if it works then and then if it does try to reinstall the Unity URP and Shader Graph. If it didn't work without the URP and Shader Graph then it means you have an error in your code and you should debug it.

I created another project, and then copied the assets from the first project to the second, everything went normally, including when I added the URP and the graphic shader.

Alright then thats good you don't need to worry anymore.

Some solutions to try:

Does this happen if you create a new project and install the same packages?
Try restarting your pc
Try reinstalling the Unity editor
People have reported that deleting the Library folder in your project folder (more specifically the Bee folder in the Library folder) may be a solution. Backup your project before trying.
Try creating a compilation error in your project to force it into safe mode by going into your Assets folder in your project folder, and creating an error in one of your .cs files.


The Library folder doesn't need to be backed up and must never be committed to source control. It can be deleted at any time and will be recreated when Unity loads the project. It is just a cache.

I created another project, and added the same packages, the project was normal, I already tried restarting the PC and it didn't work, I reinstalled the unity editor and it didn't work, I already deleted the bee and library folders and activated safe mode by creating a compilation error in a script, it didn't work either, it always stays in "Compilling Scripts: ScriptCompilation: Running Backend".

@Skar_saN can you try backing up your project and then removing the packages you installed and any other ones that might be causing problems from Packages/manifest.json in your project folder. This should remove them from the project.

Remove the package, how do you say it? Because I can't access the project, to remove it, would I need to edit the manifest.json?

@Skar_saN yes, you would need modify the manifest.json, and unity wouldn't load the packages you remove when you load the project.
